# How to export C++ data to a C# struct?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, dllexport

I'm struggling to export a C++ struct data to C#.

Say I have the following structure representing a 3-floating-points vector:

```
// C++
struct fvec3
{
public:
    float x, y, z;
    fvec3(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) { }
};

// C#
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct fvec3
{
    public float x, y, z;

    public fvec3(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

Now, if I wanted to use a `fvec3` from C# to C++, I can use the following without a problem:

```
// C++
__declspec(dllexport) void Import(fvec3 vector)
{
    std::cout << vector.x << " " << vector.y << " " << vector.z;
}

// C#
[DllImport("example.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Import(fvec3 vector);

...

Import(new fvec3(1, 2, 3)); // Prints "1 2 3".
```

The problem now is to do the opposite: return a C++ `fvec3` to C#. How can I do this?
I've seen many C# implementations use something along the lines of this:

```
// C#
[DllImport("example.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Export(out fvec3 vector);

...

fvec3 vector;
Export(out vector); // vector contains the value given by C++
```

**But how do I write the C++ `Export` function?**

I tried everything I could think about for both the signature and the body:

```
// Signatures: 
__declspec(dllexport) void Export(fvec3 vector)
__declspec(dllexport) void Export(fvec3* vector)
__declspec(dllexport) void Export(fvec3& vector)

// Bodies (with the pointer variants)
vector = fvec3(1, 2, 3);
memcpy(&fvec3(1, 2, 3), &vector, sizeof(fvec3));
*vector = new fvec(1, 2, 3);
```

Some of these have no effet, some return garbage values, and some cause crashes.

Comment: How do I write the C++ `Export` function?

Comment: Do you have problems with the signature or with the body? What did you already try?

Comment: Added some of my tries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ref` and `out` parameters are usually matched with pointer arguments.

Try this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void Export(fvec3 *vector)
{
    *vector = fvec3(1, 2, 3);
}
```

*(Untested)*

---

Alternatively, you should be able to simply return a `fvec3` from your function:

```
// C++
__declspec(dllexport) fvec3 Export(void)
{
    return fvec3(1, 2, 3);
}

// C#
[DllImport("example.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern fvec3 Export();

...

fvec3 vector = Export();
```

*(Untested)*